# Redshift SQL query help needed

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Table `order_details`:

```
order_id   dish_id     category_id
----------------------------------
   601        22            123
   601        23            234
   603        32            456
   603        54            456
   603        11            543
   603        19            456
```

From the sample table provided above: how can I group the `order_id,dish_id` and `category_id` on the basis of distinct group with respect to each `order_id`?

The result should look like

```
order_id   dish_id     category_id     count
---------------------------------------------
   601        22            123          1
   601        23            234          1
   603        32            456          3
   603        54            452          3
   603        11            543          3
   603        19            456          3
```

Note:

Like `dish_id 22` in `order_id 601` went along with 1 different distinct `category_id` i.e `234`, and similarly in `order_id 603 dish_id 32` went along 2 different distinct `category_id` ie `456, 543`

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Also, your numbers don't make sense.  Why are the values for 603 "2" instead of "3"?

Comment: Sorry it was typo,
 my bad,
 thanks for pointing  it out

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the triplets are unique, you seem to want 1 less than the count of the group.  That would be:

```
select t.*,
       (count(*) over (partition by order_id) - 1) as cnt
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff it works perfectly for provided data set ,
But if i insert one more column in result table like 
'603, 02 , 543'

So now the count of distinct category_id comes out to be 4,
 which is in correct since category_id 543 is being ol ready present in order_id 603  the count shuld still be 3
How can i do tht in above query
thnx in advance

Comment: Does `count(distinct category_id)` work in Redshift?

Comment: No sir it didn't it got me error while executing it

Comment: @GordonLinoff: `count(distinct category_id)` works in Redshift.

Comment: @ankitkhanduri: Do let us know what error are you getting. That might be due to a mistake from your end.

Comment: @YusufHassan
Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: WINDOW definition is not supported;
Query used 
select stack_del.*,
       (count(distinct category_id) over (partition by order_id) - 1) as 
from stack_del;

Comment: Okkkay @ankitkhanduri: So the WINDOW function is not accepting aggregates. Write an inner query and calculate `count(distinct category_id)` and use it in the outer query with WINDOW function. There'll be no stopping :)